# Send second request on ajax done()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request as follows:

```
var xurl = 'some-url';
var secondurl = 'some-other-url'
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: xurl,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(domains),
      beforeSend: function(){
          $('div.sending').html('Sending request...');
      },
      success: function (data) {
         //
      },
      error: function (x, t, m) {
         //
      }
      });
```

My question is that can I send another call on `done` of the original ajax call?

I've written it as follows:

```
....)}//ajax post request ends here
.done({
      url: secondurl,
      success: function(){
          $('div.sending').html('Done!!');
      }
});
```

Is this the right way? If yes, any idea why the ajax call on done doesn't send `secondurl` as a call?

Comment: You're missing a quote.

Comment: @Daedalus, I've not copied my exact code from my IDE to here but wrote it from scratch so I must've made mistakes. Will fix

Comment: @Newtt: Inside the `.done()` block of the first ajax call , you need to make another instance `$.ajax()` and then pass the required parameters to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.done() accepts a function as a argument, not an object so

```
$.ajax({...}).done(function(){
    $.ajax({...})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

done() will be fired when the deferred is resolved,
go through this link
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

you can use deferred.then() to add new handler to add handlers to be called when the Deferred object is resolved, rejected.